# use printf("text %d", number) type format to assign value to variable

Tags: c++, c

I would like to use the syntax that printf uses, using the %d, %s and adding values after to assign a value to a char[]. Is this possible?

e.g. Given an output of:

```
printf("now: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
```

I'd like to assign that to char[] output;

How can this be done?

I tried:

```
sprintf(output, "now: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
```

but that didn't seem to work. Is sprintf used differently... or is that not what I should be using?

Thanks!

EDIT: It turned out I simply needed to increase the initialized length of output...

Comment: "Didn't seem to work" in what way? Looks alright to me, assuming the buffer's big enough. For that reason consider snprintf instead.

Comment: That is the proper syntax for sprintf() what error are you getting specifically?

Comment: Ah, that is probably the issue... output is assigned earlier and I need to assigned it with the new data. How would I change the size of the array, since I know the size after the change?

Comment: Use (_)scprintf to determine the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work fine provided you have enough space in the output buffer (at least 26 bytes) to take the largest string you'll create:

```
char output[26];
sprintf(output, "now: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n",
    tm.tm_year + 1900,
    tm.tm_mon + 1,
    tm.tm_mday,
    tm.tm_hour,
    tm.tm_min,
    tm.tm_sec);
```

You need:

- 5 for `"now:  "`.
- 4 for the year (for at least the next 79 centuries).
- 2 each for the other five numerics.
- 5 for the separators (`"-- ::"`).
- 1 for the newline.
- 1 for the terminating null character.

You may also want to consider changing the format string to `"now: %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d"` so that the datetimes will line up if you're outputting them, to avoid something like:

```
2009-12-31 23:59:58 blah blah blah
2010-1-1 0:0:7 yada yada yada
```

when

```
2009-12-31 23:59:58 blah blah blah
2010-01-01 00:00:07 yada yada yada
```

looks so much better. You'll notice I've left the `"\n"` off the end - since this is the sort of code you see a lot in logging, you'd want the datetime to be in a format you could easily append to, something like:

```
fprintf (logFile, "%s Cannot write to '%s', error = %d\n",
    output, fileSpec, errno);
```

If I've misunderstood what you're using this for, feel free to ignore the last few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be on the safe side I suggest using snprintf instead of sprintf.  This will keep you away from the nasty surprises.

http://libslack.org/manpages/snprintf.3.html

Answer (score 0):

So long as output has enough space your syntax should work.

```
output = (char *)malloc( 1000 ); //or some other large enough number
sprintf( output, control string, . . . );
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: many modern C runtime libraries implement the "scprintf" (or "_scprinf") function, that returns the number of characters that would be generated by sprintf with the same format and arguments (e.g. here the description of [Microsoft Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32cf9tb(VS.80).aspx)).
The main problem is that the format/parameters evaluation is done twice, with a considerable performace loss. If it's not a problem for you, you can use the value returned by scprinf to dynamically allocate a buffer of the required size. Also, as optimization, you can recycle the allocated buffer to reduce the frequency of allocations (they indeed tend to zero). Example (NOTE: multithreading issues ignored here)

```
int nchr;
static int last_size = 0;
static char *buff = NULL;
char *new_buff;

nchr = _scprintf(format, /* ...args... */) + 1;
if (last_size < nchr) {
     new_buff = malloc(nchr);
     if (new_buff == NULL) { /* ERROR... */ }
     if (buff != NULL) {
           free(buff);
     }
     buff = new_buff;
     last_size = nchr;
}
sprinf(buff, format, /* ...args... */);
```